# Calculating the log-likelihood of a set of observations sampled from a mixture of two normal distributions using R

Tags: r, log-likelihood

I wrote a function to calculate the log-likelihood of a set of observations sampled from a mixture of two normal distributions.  This function is not giving me the correct answer.

I will not know which of the two distributions any given sample is from, so the function needs to sum over possibilities.

This function takes a vector of five model parameters as its first argument (μ1, σ1​, μ2​, σ2​ and p) where μi​ and σi​ are the mean and standard deviation of the ith distribution and p is the probability a sample is from the first distribution.  For the second argument, the function takes a vector of observations.

I have written the following function:

```
mixloglik <- function(p, v) {
    sum(log(dnorm(v, p[1], p[2])*p[5] + dnorm(v,p[3],p[4]))*p[5])
}
```

I can create test data, for which I know the solution should be ~ -854.6359:

```
set.seed(42)
v<- c(rnorm(100), rnorm(200, 8, 2))
p <- c(0, 1, 6, 2, 0.5)
```

When I test this function on the test data I do not get the correct solution

```
> mixloglik(p, v)
[1] -356.7194
```

I know the solution should be ~ -854.6359.  Where am I going wrong in my function?

Comment: In the second term of the log-likelihood it's `(1- p[5])`.

Comment: I've now corrected this in the code but it shouldn't matter much in this example as 1-p[5] is the same as p[5].

Comment: Done, see the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct expression for the log-likelihood is the following.

```
mixloglik <- function(p, v) {
  sum(log(p[5]*dnorm(v, p[1], p[2]) + (1 - p[5])*dnorm(v, p[3], p[4])))
}
```

Now try it:

```
set.seed(42)
v<- c(rnorm(100), rnorm(200, 8, 2))
p <- c(0, 1, 6, 2, 0.5)
mixloglik(p, v)
#[1] -854.6359
```

In cases like this, the best way to solve the error is to restart by rewriting the expression *on paper* and recode it.